# How to sort a very-2 huge file when total RAM is very low

Tags: unix

How to sort a file which is very huge in size in order of few hundred GB on a machine where memory is very low. Due to this we can not open the file as memory is not sufficient.Any pointers in this regard would be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot open the file?  You mean you cannot read it all into memory at once, yes?

Comment: Doesn't [GNU sort](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html) just work? It has all kinds of optimizations and buffer-size options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by 'cannot open the file', you really mean 'cannot read/map the entire file into memory', Google for 'merge sort' - it's useable when the data can only be accessed sequentially.

Comment: Thanks Martin. "Merge sort" looks to be answer.